# OnItemClickListener for a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add on item click listener to my `RecyclerView` so that when i click on a certain item, it starts a new `Intent` and retrieves data from a web server about that item. I've tried a lot of suggestions but non of them helped.

**My RecylerView Class**

```
public class GetPrice extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private  CustomAdapter adapter;
private List<MyData> dataList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getpricerecycle);
    recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    load_data_from_server(0);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,dataList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void load_data_from_server(final int id) {
    AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://172.20.10.7/anfal/getPrice.php?id="+id).build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++ ){
                    JSONObject jsonobject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    MyData data=new MyData(jsonobject.getInt("id"),jsonobject.getString("name"),jsonobject.getString("price"),jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    dataList.add(data);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("End Of Content");
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
task.execute(id);

}
```

**here is my coustm Adapter for the recycler view**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {                                                                 
        private Context context;
        private List<MyData> my_data;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.getpricecardview,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           holder.name.setText(my_data.get(position).getName());
           holder.price.setText(my_data.get(position).getPrice());


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView price;
        public ImageView imageview;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            price=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameofp);
            imageview=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgevie);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970486/1563038

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to implement item click of recyclerview is to implement in onBindViewHolder method of an adapter.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
       vh.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //use position value  to get clicked data from list
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `RecyclerView.Adapter` simply create an interface you can use.

```
private onItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public interface onItemClickListener {
    void onItemClickListener(View view, int position, MyData myData);
}
```

In this case `mItemClickListener` is a global variable inside your adapter and the two methods go inside your adapter, too.

Then inside your `ViewHolder` apply a click listener to your `itemView` with `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)` (or whatever component you want clicked to retrieve the data)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mItemClickListener != null) {
        mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(view, getAdapterPosition(), my_data.get(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}
```

This will then pass the view that has been clicked, the position of said view and the object that is contained in your list within that position.

So in your `Activity`, you can then just simply call the `interface`.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapter.onItemItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position, MyData data) {
    //do on item click functionality here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First way

```
recyclerViewObject.addOnItemTouchListener(
        new RecyclerItemClickListener(
            getContext(),
            recyclerViewObject,
            new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // view is the clicked view (the one you wanted
                    // position is its position in the adapter
                }
                @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                }
            }
        )
    );
```

Second way

```
public interface PositionClickListener {
    void itemClicked(int position); }
```

in adapter

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public final PositionClickListener listener;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(PositionClickListener listener)
    {
         this.listener = listener;
    }

    private void createView(int position)
    {
        View v = new View();
        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            listener.itemClicked(position);
        });
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970389/defining-a-recyclerviews-onclicklistener-in-an-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best practice with recyclerView and OnClickListener is to do this way :

In your activity:

```
//Add this line in the onCreate method
//Add more parameters if needed for your adapter
DataAdapter myDataAdapter = new DataAdapter (context, myClickListener);


private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        int position = view.getTag()
        //Do something...
    }
};
```

And in your adapter

```
private View.OnClickListener myClickListener;
private Context context;

 public DataAdapter (Context context, View.OnClickListener myClickListener)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
{

    //Your attributes

    public myViewHolder(View v, View.OnClickListener myClickListener) 
    {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.itemView.setTag(position)
}
```

Of course it works for any kind of clickListener.

Hope this help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can just change ViewHolder

```
         public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            price=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameofp);
            imageview=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgevie);



            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here is the action


                }
            });


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click event to itemView inside CustomAdapter.ViewHolder

I.e. itemView.setOnClickListener() And inside onClick() Method get position of clicked item like this:

getAdapterPosition()