# How to fix "NullPointerException" on ViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to do the clickable `RecyclerView`, I watched a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970389/defining-a-recyclerviews-onclicklistener-in-an-activity/35970486#35970486)  on how to do it, but it gave me interface `NullPointerException` when I click the `RecyclerView`.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    private ViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

    public interface ClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition()); //Line that called the Exception
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is it something that has to do with the interface? Do I need to pass the interface to adapter like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970389/defining-a-recyclerviews-onclicklistener-in-an-activity/35970486#35970486) suggests?

Here's the exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.jobseeker.ViewHolder$ClickListener.onItemClick(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.jobseeker.ViewHolder$1.onClick(ViewHolder.java:32)
...etc.
```

Here's the adapter

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(options) {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView mCompNameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rCompNameTv);
                TextView mDescTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rDescTv);
                TextView mPosTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rPosTv);
                ImageView mImageTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rImageIv);

                String mCompName = mCompNameTv.getText().toString();
                String mDesc = mDescTv.getText().toString();
                String mPos = mPosTv.getText().toString();
                Drawable mDrawable = mImageTv.getDrawable();
                Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

                Intent intent = new Intent(viewGroup.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                intent.putExtra("image", bytes);
                intent.putExtra("companyName", mCompName);
                intent.putExtra("description", mDesc);
                intent.putExtra("position", mPos);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {
        holder.setDetails(model.getCompanyName(), model.getDescription(), model.getPosition(), model.getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
    }
};
```

Comment: You're not initializing `mClickListener` in any of the code you provided, which would be why you're getting an NPE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: have you create Interface class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have not initialized your `ViewHolder` class with the listener attribute. Use the `setOnClickListener` function to initialize the `ViewHolder`.

Hence your return statement from `onCreateViewHolder` might look like the following.

```
ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
vh.setOnClickListener(clickListener); // Initialize a click listener in your Activity maybe and pass it here.
return vh;
```

I would like to suggest checking [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49969478/3145960) for a better understanding of how you can achieve the click listening in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I tried your answer but it gave me another exception. What i understand from the logcat there is two item click. The one from ViewHolder and another one in the adapter

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system...etc...at com.example.jobseeker.MainHomeFragment.JobListFragment$2$1.onItemClick(JobListFragment.java:157)
        at com.example.jobseeker.ViewHolder$1.onClick(ViewHolder.java:32)

Comment: Did you check my answer that I provided a link to?

Comment: I did. I just re-did the adapter and now it works. Thanks